# How to load a storyboard from a XIB file?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder, storyboard

I am trying to load a storyboard file from a XIB file when a button is clicked. So in the `IBAction` method I have called the following line:

```
- (IBAction)NextView:(id)sender
{
            UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryViewController"];
}
```

But I get this error when I run the application
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x88672d0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'StoryViewController''`

I check out other questions asked by people on stackverflow and found that generally this error is thrown when one forgets to put the identifier name of the View controller in the identity inspector for the view controller that one is trying to load. But I have done that too.
In the storyboard the first viewController which is getting loaded is `StoryViewController` and I have set its identifier the same. Is there something else that I may be missing. Please tell me how to correct it.
[image]

Comment: Try typing `StoryViewController` into the `Storyboard ID` field and see if it fixes the problem. Currently, you specify only the custom class; it's not the name of the view controller in the storyboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting the class name of the view controller only. I can see that the storyboard ID filed as empty. Set the **Storyboard ID**  to ***StoryViewController*** in the ***Identity*** section

[image]

```
- (IBAction)NextView:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    StoryViewController *storyViewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryViewController"]; 
    [self presentViewController:storyViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; //  present it  
     //[self.navigationController pushViewController:storyViewController animated:YES];// or push it

 }
```

Comment: Thanks I got rid of the error. But after doing as you suggested, clicking the button in which I had written the code to load storyboard doesn't do anything. Can you tell what is wrong with it now?

Comment: the code you written will return an instance of the StoryViewController. Then you have to present or push that view controller

Comment: I added these two lines in the -(IBAction) method . `StoryViewController *SVC= [[StoryViewController alloc]init]; [self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:NULL];`
But when I clicked the button it loaded an empty white screen and not the 3 buttons as shown in the screen shot above as I have not written any code in the `StoryViewController.m` file. I want to load the contents in the storyboard how to do that.

Comment: about the edited answer:
My view controller is a sub class of UIViewController and not of UINavigationController.

Comment: Dont alloc init.. it will give empty view only...load from storyboard.. i have edited my answer check

Comment: Anil.. Thanks yaar. It worked. I have one last request. Please post the code in comment here that you had posted previously for presenting the view for a NavigationViewController. I have another project which has NavigationViewController. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30494/discussion-between-mk-singh-and-anil)