# Checking for Null and inserting a value if null is found

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on a project and have just added a new field to a table and would like my application to find the null values in that field and set them to 1 as a default. This is what I have so far.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

```
sqlCN = new SqlConnection(strCOM);
try
{
    sqlCN.Open();
    sqlCOM = new SqlCommand("select f_ProviderType from t_Provider", sqlCN);

    sqlDR = sqlCOM.ExecuteReader();

    if (sqlDR.IsDBNull(0))
    {
        sqlstr = "INSERT INTO t_Provider(f_Provider_Type) VALUES  (1)";
    }

    sqlDR.Close();

}
catch (DataException ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    sqlCN.Close();
    sqlDR = null;
    sqlCOM = null;
    sqlCN = null;
}
```

Comment: `UPDATE t_Provider SET f_ProviderType=1 WHERE f_ProviderType IS NULL`?

Comment: OMG you post the solution here and everyone copies it to the ANSWER...no words

Comment: @AnnArbor87 This question is essentially a "typing contest". It takes much longer to type a full answer than a comment, explaining the appearance of "copying someone's comment into an answer". This happens often, especially on simpler questions. Here is [just one example from this morning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713460/how-to-load-a-storyboard-from-a-xib-file#comment24060662_16713460), but this happens routinely here.

Comment: (aside) you should really look at using the Using statement for both the connection and command

Comment: @AnnArbor87 I don't mind, I was just passing by and thought I'd get the discussion started :) Had I had the time to write an answer then, I would have.

Comment: So people worried about reputation, :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written is not going to work (it's going to *insert new rows* instead of updating the existing ones), and it's also pretty inefficient.  You could instead just run the following SQL:

```
UPDATE t_Provider SET f_ProviderType = 1 WHERE f_ProviderType IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
update t_Provider set f_Provider_Type=1 WHERE f_ProviderType IS NULL
```