# How to load a xib file from a storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder, storyboard

I am new to iOS programming and I am working on a project which will use both XIB files and storyboard.
I have two modules in it basically. First module is made from XIB files which also runs independently. I have made another module using storyboard and I had to integrate these two independently running modules. The screen of my first module  which I want to connect to my storyboard is a subclass of UIViewController and I was able to do that with the help of stackoverflow ([How to load a storyboard from a XIB file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713460/how-to-load-a-storyboard-from-a-xib-file)) by creating an object of UIStoryBoard. Now my application is able to go to the storyboard but I can't come back to my first module which is made up of XIB files.

Please let me know how can I connect to the same instance of the last screen of the first module through which storyboard is called so that I can move back and forth through these views easily. Connecting to the same instance of the XIB file is important because it is a chat screen and when I come back to this screen, I would like to get back to the chat where I had left it and also when I come back to the storyboard (by clicking a button on the chat screen) I have a slider on the screen which should display the value which the user must have chosen when they were on this screen last time. I guess creating a new object should give me a new screen which won't work in this situation. This kind of mechanism works well within storyboard with the use of segue where we can define both source and destination view controller.

Please help me achieve the same in my situation.

Please also check the screen shots of the XIB file and the storyboard which I want connected.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: in the example you used  `[self presentViewController:storyViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

so cant you just Dismiss the `storyViewController`

Comment: Yes and that is the problem. When I again have to go to that storyboard, I will again go to the `-IBAction` and there a new object would be created for a storyboard and that object would again initialize my slider to the default value and not to the one where the user had left it last time. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: but you can allways check to see if the storyboard has been instantiated or not 
 `if(mainStoryBoard!=nil) {
*mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryViewController"];
}`

Comment: In the code above what I think is happening is that first it is being checked that whether the object of storyboard is initialised.
If no then it would take the previous object which must have been initialised last time. And the code for that would be outside `if`. I will try this maybe this will work but that would be the solution to the later part of my problem. First of all how do I go back to the viewController of the XIB file where I should test your code?

Comment: you can save the `lastSceenViewController` Object as a property in `appdelegate` and use `[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` to access that object.

Comment: come back means you are trying to pop?

Comment: @LithuT.V: By coming back to my first module I mean just a transition to the previous screen like we move around different screens with the help of a Navigation view controller.

Comment: @Bonnie: Your last suggestion may solve my problems. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the nib files into storyboard, it will help you easier to manage your application.

Comment: I know that, but I want a solution to my problem in the present scenario. I just want to know to get a smooth connection between a XIB file and a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your case, what i see is from nibs is that there is a navigation controller  in storyboard and also there will be a root view controller navigation controller from xib files.
Well the navigation controller stack has all VCs you pushed into and you can get back it in different ways.